# Unity.Mvc vs Unity.Mvc5 differences

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5, unity-container, ioc-container

I just started to learn  ASP.NET MVC 5 and found a lot of tutorials about using the Unity ioc container for dependency injection.

I followed this great video to start: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E7Voso411Vs

when looking for the package to install, I saw:

[image]

I found [this](https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2014/10/27/up-and-running-with-unity-ioc-container-for-asp-net-mvc/) tutorial from October 2014 that shows how to use the **Unity.Mvc** framework. All it required is:

1. adding the package (automatically adding `UnityConfig.cs` and `UnityMvcActivator.cs` to App_Start.
2. create interface (`IUnitySample` for example) and an implementation
3. adding a constructor to `HomeController` for example that takes a `IUnitySample` as a parameter.
4. and finally, add to `UnityConfig.cs` in method RegisterTypes the register statement: `container.RegisterType<IUnitySample, UnitySample>();`

**No need to add anything in** `Application_Start` method.

That seems very easy and it works, but from the more updated tutorials I read, it shows that people are using the **Unity.Mvc5** package and not the Unity.Mvc.

What should I use to learn ASP.NET MVC 5? what are the differences between them? is one better than the other?

Answer (score 4):

[Unity.Mvc5](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.Mvc5/) and [Unity.Mvc](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.Mvc/) are created by two different organizations and have different implementations.

**Unity.Mvc5** creates a child container per web request. This works well with the built-in `HierarchicalLifetimeManager`.

**Unity.Mvc** does not create a child container, but instead chose to create a new LifetimeManager called `PerRequestLifetimeManager`.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I consider Unity.Mvc a better choice for its statistics (e.g .: total downloads) and because it shows a higher frequency of updates in the "Version History". Therefore it seems to be more followed.